# What would be the best way to save arrays in SQLite?

Tags: iphone, arrays, sqlite

I'm trying to add an array into an SQLite Database on an iPhone.  The thing is, I do not know how many array objects the user will want to use.  It may be 1, it may be 10.  If I allocated 10 fields in a SQLite Table, that would be 9 wastes if the user was to use one, and it would put an upper bound to 10 entries.

Thus I thought of using a single VARCHAR type field, and adding each object of the array with a special character between each objects. How would this be performance wise? Any better ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess will be to use the NSCoder framework. As NSArray conforms to NSCoding protocol, the serialization is already done to you:

```
  NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
  [archiver encodeObject:myArray forKey:myArchiveKey];
  [archiver finishEncoding];
  [archiver release];

  // write here data object to a BLOB field of your SQLite db
```

Decoding will be very similar

Comment: Oh Boy! I totally forgot about NSCoding! I think this would do the trick!

Comment: Strictly speaking even better design would be not to store the fields of the array in the same table as the other elements of your record:

Comment: Records (id, etc.)
Arrays (recordId, order, element)
Thus for a given record you can store as much element you want in order in the second table. Then you do a JOIN on the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could save them as OBJECT columns.

Comment: Does SQLite have a OBJECT type field?

Comment: I think it does. I use it from Adobe Air, to develop for iOS, and use it all the time. Unless, there is some translation to BLOB behind the scene.

Comment: Do you mean Using a BLOB table? The [SQLite Documentation](http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html) doesn't specify any OBJECT type.

Comment: Quite interesting: I have just opened one of my SQLite databases using an editor (Lita) and the column data type shows as OBJECT, although this data type is not in the SQLite documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can store array entries as rows.

Comment: Only if they are the same length...or have a reasonable max length.

Answer (score 0):

you can save the array in json object format and while retrieving convert the json object to array.

Comment: JSON sounds like an interesting approach! But as of now I'll try NSCoding first. Thanks @Passionate!